# JOSM file associations

Tags: java, file-association

If I download JOSM from the Ubuntu repo, I get a somewhat outdated version, but sound files attached to a GPX track will open directly in Totem, the associated application.

If, however, I download the latest JOSM version from the website and run it, these sound files will open in a new tab in Firefox (which will in turn open Totem).

How can I make JOSM follow the system-wide file association? (That is, how does the package from the Ubuntu repo do it?) I use <del>OpenJDK 8</del> OpenJDK 7 on Ubuntu MATE 14.10.

**Edit:**

I've copied the JOSM JAR from the repo into my home folder and run it directly (the way I run the downloaded version), still the file associations work (audio opens in Totem). Settings and plugins are shared between the two JOSM installations.

Ubuntu's JOSM is started through a script. I've tried modifying this script to point to my downloaded copy of JOSM, but still the audio files open in the browser.

That would imply that file associations are in the JOSM code. However, I had the correct file association in a JOSM copy downloaded from the website on my old Ubuntu 12.04 setup (which I have replaced with Ubuntu MATE 14.10).

Comment: Since I remember earlier versions honored file associations, I have filed a bug: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/11017